# How can I make plotly save html where I want it

Tags: r, plotly

I am using `plotly` (NOT IN `RStudio`) and when I plot something it is supposed to be rendered in the browser.
However I get the following:

```
"Firefox can't find the file at /tmp/Rtmpv5uV66/viewhtml84af507e6221/index.html."
```

The problem is that I run firefox on another machine (I have no choice in my setup) but I have a shered directory that could be used.

Is it possible to tell plotly (if `plotly` is in charge) to save in another directory ?

Comment: Could you assign the plot to an object, then use `htmlwidgets::saveWidget()` on the object?

Comment: Yes that's working, it is a little cumbersome but good for now, thanks